# Best way to handle a case where FileSystemWatcher in C# ISN'T thread safe?

Tags: c#, asp.net, thread-safety

**Note:** There are a lot of questions on stack overflow regarding thread safety and FileSystemWatcher, but they all end in mostly the same result: it's thread safe and you only need to mess with threads if you're incorporating it into a gui of some sort. However, I have a case where I can't figure out if what I have is thread safe or not and I'm looking for advise on what to do.

**THE CONTEXT:**
I have a FileSystemWatcher object that watches a log file (simple .txt) for changes. If the file changes, it reads the file (but only the newest content added) and stores the data in another variable/object.

```
private  void onChangeSystem(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e) {
            tailFileCmd(ref system, 5);
        }

private  void tailFileCmd(ref Logs log, int tailAmount = 75) {
            if (log.safeToRead) {
                log.lines.Clear();
                var result = CMDder.ExecuteCmd("tail -" + tailAmount.ToString() + " " + log.location);
                if (!result.HasError && result.ExitCode == 0) {
                    var split = result.Result.Split('\n');
                    if (split.Length > 0) {
                        foreach (string line in split) {
                            log.lines.Add(line);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I have to deal with multiple files later, so I created a class to store all the data needed for each file, including its own watcher. I do wonder if having the watcher and the file content in the same object will be problematic though.

```
public class Logs {
        public logType type = logType.NOT_SET;
        public string location = string.Empty;
        public StreamReader? file;
        public FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
        public List<string> lines = new List<string>();
        public bool safeToRead = false;
    }
```

The boolean at the is set to true during initialization of the object if the file paths are correct and both StreamReader and FileSystemWatcher are initialized correctly. CMDer is a custom class (from another project) imported in that just executes system commands. I know it's not required but I'm just using it for simplicity here. Also, the existence of a StreamReader is for use later (which will also need to be thread safe, but one problem at a time).

The above code works in that it keeps the lines list up to date with the most recent content, and only updates if the file changes.

**THE PROBLEM:**
I have another function in another file that will be making regular calls to get the data from the logs object, specifically the lines, in order to pass it off somewhere else. With the current setup I have, I do not believe this is thread-safe (but it's difficult to test in my case as I'd have to get the timings perfectly lined up). If my theory is correct, how do I make the above code thread-safe so that if the lines list is being updated at the exact same time that I try to read it, one of the functions (doesn't matter which one) waits for the other to finish first before going? I don't have a lot of experience with threads in C#, only in C++.

**EDIT:** There seems to be some confusion regarding what is going on with my code. To clarify, the code is NOT modifying the file. The file gets modified by an entirely different program. When I say I'm writing, I'm referring to storing the contents OF THE FILE to a variable that is a list of strings, where each string is a line in the file.

Comment: And where is the thread ?

Comment: The problem here is not a thread ... but shared access to the file, I think

Comment: If the problm is really threading in your app you can simply use `lock`

Comment: @Selvin I haven't added it yet because I don't know the best way to go about doing this, hence the question here. I don't know if I need to put FileSystemWatcher in its own thread and then add safety to it, because doing research on that says you don't need to, but the context isn't like what I'm doing.

Answer (score 1):

If the writer and reader of the file is within the same process, you should probably use some other method to update the data. Your logging framework might have some custom log writer that allow you to intercept log messages without having to re-read them from file, or you could just create a decorator for your logger interface that does the same thing. In either case, a lock around a regular list should be sufficient to ensure reading and writing cannot be done concurrently.

If the writer is in another process you can use a named [mutex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.mutex?view=net-7.0) to create a cross process lock,  but this will require changes to both processes. You might also consider using some inter process communication method instead of a file, that will likely be more reliable. I have heard rumors that `FileSystemWatcher` is not very reliable, that might be due to incorrect usage, but I would probably prefer other methods if possible.

If modification of the writer is not possible I'm not sure how it should be done. Locking the file might cause the writing process to fail. Maybe create a shadow copy of the file?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific about that. Both reading the file and writing it's contents to the list of lines is in the same class. The part that isn't in the same class is an http call that asks for the lines and returns them to a web gui, where the call is in another C# controller class, hence why asp.net was included in the tags. The class that handles the file contents is injected into the controller so that the controller can access it.

Comment: *Both reading the file and writing it's contents to the list of lines is in the same class.* Then what is the purpose of  using `FileSystemWatcher` ?

Comment: @Selvin because I only want to read the file if it changes. If it doesn't change, don't read it.

Comment: @Deoxys_0 If the class writes to the file, there is *no* reason to read the same file (except possibly on startup), just change the code that does the writing to also update a common list. There is no reason to use `FileSystemWatcher`. *you already know when, and how, the file changes*

Comment: @JonasH the code doesn't write anything to the file at all. When I say write, I'm referring to storing the contents of the file in a variable, not modifying the actual file.

Comment: @Deoxys_0 Then what is the purpose of the `FileSystemWatcher` ? Who changes the file?

Comment: @JonasH another program that runs in the background changes the file. It's not a program I wrote and is part of a larger system I'm working in.

Comment: @Deoxys_0 Then see paragraph 3. If you cannot change the process that writes to the file there is no good way to ensure the data is consistent, at least none I know of. You can fix *your* program so it is 'thread safe', but you can still have concurrency issues due to lack of synchronization with the third party program.